# Why does \ref show A instead of A1?

Tags: cross-referencing, appendix

I want to know why when I'm using /ref{} it only show A, but I'm actually are referring to A1.

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}
\appendix

\section{Vedlegg Arbeidspakker}

\includepdf[scale=0.85,pages=1,pagecommand=
\subsection{Lekkasjedeteksjon på ledningsnett},offset=0 -3cm]{../vedlegg/ArbeidspakkeLekkasjedeteksjon.pdf}
\label{atc:ArbeidspakkeLekkasjedeteksjon}

\includepdf[scale=0.85,pages=1,pagecommand=
\subsection{Flomsikring},offset=0 -3cm]{../vedlegg/ArbeidspakkeFlomsikring.pdf}
\label{atc:ArbeidspakkeFlomsikring}

\section{Vedlegg Tidsplan}

\includepdf[scale=1,pages=-,pagecommand=
\subsection{Timeplanlegging},offset=0 -3cm]{../vedlegg/Timeplanlegging.pdf}
\label{atc:Timeplanlegging}

\includepdf[scale=1,pages=-,pagecommand=
\subsection{Gantt},offset=0 -3cm]{../vedlegg/Gantt.pdf}
\label{atc:Gantt}


\end{document}
```

Example:

```
Se vedlegg \ref{atc:Timeplanlegging} og \ref{atc:Gantt}.
```

Become "Se vedlegg B og B", but they are B.1 and B.2 from TOC.

[image]

Is it possible to change it so B og B become B.1 and B.2

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se, and thanks for adding a sample document. But unfortunately this document doesn't really help, since it depends completely on included files we don't have. Can you reproduce your problem without these files, and then edit your question to show that document?

Comment: Try putting the `\label` commands inside the `\subsection` code.

Comment: That actually did the trick Alan! Thank you. And yes, I will try to come up with a better sample next time.

Comment: Since your question code is hard to reproduce, I suggest we close the question as a duplicate of [Understanding how references and labels work](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280)

Comment: Yes, thats ok. Thanks again :)